# How do I permanently reset the UUID of an LVM partition?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm, uuid

A (dd cloned) backup of my boot partition left me with duplicate UUIDs.

`blkid` shows:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="32579810-0388-416d-bb49-7031ac2c2975" TYPE="ext4"
...
/dev/mapper/raidgroup-osbackup: UUID="32579810-0388-416d-bb49-7031ac2c2975" TYPE="ext4"
...
```

where `/dev/mapper/raidgroup-osbackup` is an LVM device.

I booted from a live Ubuntu image and tried:

```
sudo tune2fs -U random /dev/mapper/raidgroup-osbackup
```

This appeared to succeed and the target device showed a new UUID.

However, after reboot `/dev/mapper/raidgroup-osbackup` was remounted at `/` and `blkid` showed the original UUID.

I thought the change with `tune2fs` was supposed to be permanent, but this does not seem to be the case. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you perhaps cloning the entire filesystem? You might want to look into the “Skip Activation” flag for LVM.

Comment: I think the duplicate UUID indeed comes from cloning the entire file system with `dd`. It seems it should be easily solved by simply changing the UUID of the backed-up partition. But why does the UUID revert to its original value?

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have solved it now. I am not sure exactly which step solved the problem, but this time I did:

Generate new UUID:

```
uuidgen
```

This gave me a new UUID which I then copied into:

```
sudo tune2fs -U <insert here> /dev/mapper/raidgroup-osbackup
```

I then disabled the logical volume `/dev/mapper/raidgroup-osbackup` using:

```
sudo lvm lvchange -an /dev/mapper/raidgroup-osbackup
```

I disabled the other logical volumes on the same volume group and physical volume. I then disabled the underlying (software) RAID array in the "Disks" GUI. I re-enabled the RAID array in "Disks" which in turn automatically re-activated the logical volume whos file system I was messing with. Checking the UUID with `blkid`, I could now confirm that the UUID was still changed.

Just as an extra confirmation, I rebooted the Ubuntu live image and once again checked the UUID of `/dev/mapper/raidgroup-osbackup` with `blkid`. Still changed - so this part is solved now.

Along came a new problem... When rebooting the system from the ordinary install, the boot loader somehow still gets the wrong partition mounted at `/` despite the fact that the UUID is now different. I have posted this problem as a new question: [Why does Ubuntu mount the wrong partition as root?](https://superuser.com/q/833737/204260)

Answer (score 0):

This command

```
sudo udevadm trigger
```

shoud update your /dev/disk/by-uuid/ directory. Don't forget to modify your /etc/fstab file.

Hoping that's help.

Comment: It is my impression that I should not need to modify the `fstab`. I want to retain the original UUID of the partition `/dev/sda1` (which is the one I want to boot at `/`). So when this is still the UUID listed in `fstab` and I assign a new one to `/dev/mapper/raidgroup-osbackup`, I suppose I should not change the one in `fstab`?