# Find UUID under Linux?

Tags: linux, uuid

I need the UUID of a disk partition under Linux. The partition is mounted but does not show up under

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

as can happen when duplicate UUIDs exist, for example, following emergency backup using [`ddrescue`](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/).

How can I find the UUID?

Answer (score 3):

The e2fsprogs package offers `blkid`

```
$ blkid
/dev/sdb1: UUID="ac115722-c8ce-44d2-ab0c-1d284d6e4d76" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="cd6580d2-9671-4d94-b46f-0301bb563e30" TYPE="ext4" 
...
```

In table format

```
$ blkid -o list
device     fs_type label    mount point    UUID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/sdb1  ext4             /mnt/dmp1      ac115722-c8ce-44d2-ab0c-1d284d6e4d76
/dev/sda2  ext4             /              cd6580d2-9671-4d94-b46f-0301bb563e30
...
```

For a specific device

```
$ blkid /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1: UUID="ac115722-c8ce-44d2-ab0c-1d284d6e4d76" TYPE="ext4"
```

Or with no extraneous information

```
$ blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/sdb1
ac115722-c8ce-44d2-ab0c-1d284d6e4d76
```

Those subsequently wanting to change UUIDs might like these answers for [ordinary](https://superuser.com/questions/851700/change-uuid-under-linux) and [LVM](https://superuser.com/questions/833685/how-do-i-permanently-reset-the-uuid-of-a-partition/851679#851679) partitions.