# Change UUID under Linux?

Tags: linux, uuid

I need to create and assign a new UUID to an ordinary disk partition under Linux.

What tools are available and how do I use them?

Comment: Do you need to change the UUID of a _partition_ (by-partuuid) or a _filesystem_ (by-uuid)?

Answer (score 3):

Those working with ordinary disks can do this simply with `tune2fs` and `uuidgen`.

Example: using a not currently mounted device `/dev/sdb1`

```
tune2fs /dev/sdb1 -U `uuidgen`
```

The new UUID will be immediately visible under

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

if, say, you need to copy the value to /etc/fstab for automatic mount.

However, `blkid` will continue to (erroneously) report the old value until the cache is updated (on reboot, for example; though the cache may be bypassed with `sudo blkid -c /dev/null`).

Alternatively, the new UUID may be obtained via udev with

```
sudo lsblk -fo UUID /dev/sdb1
```

Those working with LVM disks might like to check the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/833685/how-do-i-permanently-reset-the-uuid-of-a-partition/851679#851679).

Comment: So it's a filesystem specific type of label? tune2fs works for ext2/3/4, or do other filesystems even have/use block id's?

Comment: It's a good question and one I hadn't considered. The filesystem I had in mind when writing is indeed ext4, but I am certainly open to answers for other filesystem contexts.

Comment: Yes, many filesystems have unique IDs (though they're not always in UUID format). Use `tune2fs -U` for ext; `xfs_admin -U` for xfs; `jfs_tune -U` for JFS; `ntfslabel --new-serial` for NTFS, and so on. (I think btrfs might not allow changing the UUID as it is extensively used internally.) Likewise, GPT partitions and LVM volumes have their own unique IDs. (The former is called a "PARTUUID" and can be seen in `by-partuuid`.)

Comment: Regarding `blkid`, it works by reading directly from the disk, and because of that it needs to cache the retrieved information somewhere accessible to ordinary users. You can bypass the cache using `blkid -c/dev/null` as root. Though, it's better to use tools like `lsblk -f`, which queries udev's automatically-updated cache.

Comment: Thanks for the insights into `blkid`'s cache, much appreciated. Answer updated to reflect this input.